# AngularJS adding css class to parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to add class to parent item with angularjs. I am new to angular and little ok with jquery. Is there any specific way to add border to the parent of parent span when there is a ng-change for a textbox control. This scenario came to me as I am trying to use a kendo date picker inside a ng-repeat and have to add a red border to control if there is any validation error. Telerik kendo datepicker adds a span as parent to textbox. so adding border color red to textbox doesnt make any sense and it has to be a border red for dynamically added parent span for kendo datepicker. I am trying to make this generic so that the same can be used through out my application.

Here is [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/97/)

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <span class="k-widget k-datepicker k-header" ng-class={{classValidationControl}} style="border: solid">
      <span class="k-picker-wrap k-state-default">
        <input type="text" kendo-date-picker="" id="endDateTextbox-0" ng-change="addBorderToControl('endDateTextbox-0')">
      <span>
      <span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-calendar">
      select
      </span>
  </span>

  <span class="k-widget k-datepicker k-header" ng-class={{classValidationControl}} style="border: solid">
      <span class="k-picker-wrap k-state-default">
        <input type="text" kendo-date-picker="" id="endDateTextbox-1" ng-change="addBorderToControl('endDateTextbox-0')">
      <span>
      <span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-calendar">
      select
      </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.addBorderToControl = function(controlName) {
    $('#' + controlName).element.parent().parent().addClass("validationControl");
  }
}
```

Comment: you want to add class to parent of parent to textbox?

Comment: yes please. I am trying to do that.

Comment: but you function `MyCtrl` not calling. i just alerted `controlName` but nothing happened

Comment: it worked with alert for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you are using Angular v1.0.1?

You have broken HTML - not closing `<span>`.

You are repeating the mistakes we all did - messing with the DOM inside controllers. You should never do this.

TL;DR
I have changed your jsFiddle to work according to the explanation ahead:

http://jsfiddle.net/mickeyvip/kqzd5q98/3/

Lets break the task apart:

The jsFiddle lacks wiring your MyCtrl to angular. You need to add:

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);
```

Now Angular can find your MyCtrl and actually run it.

But Angular will yell at you that it can't find `ngModel` - a variable on `$scope` that Angular wants to set when you change the value of the `<input>` element:

```
<input type="text" kendo-date-picker="" id="endDateTextbox-0" ng-model="startDate">

<input type="text" kendo-date-picker="" id="endDateTextbox-1" ng-model="endDate">
```

Next we will call `validateEndDate()` on input change, not `addBorderToControl()`. We actually don't need `addBorderToControl()` at all.

```
<input type="text" kendo-date-picker="" id="endDateTextbox-0" ng-model="startDate" ng-change="validateStartDate()">

<input type="text" kendo-date-picker="" id="endDateTextbox-1" ng-model="endDate" ng-change="validateEndDate()">
```

Each function will set validity on correct variable on `$scope`:

```
 $scope.validateStartDate = function() {
    // validate $scope.startDate
    var isValid = $scope.startDate === 'start';
    $scope.startDateValid = isValid;
  }

$scope.validateEndDate = function() {
    // validate $scope.endDate
    var isValid = $scope.endDate === 'end';
    $scope.endDateValid = isValid;
  }
```

For this example I will treat `startDate` as valid if it equals to `"start"` and `endDate` if it equals to `"end"`.

Now that we have all the validation logic in place, we will use Angular's directive `ng-class` on the `<span>` you need. `ng-class` was not used correctly in your sample, it expects an expression in a value of the attribute, so there is no need to wrap it in `{{ }}`. We will give it an object with key = your class name and a boolean value which will decide if we want to add this class (`true`) or remove it (`false`):

```
<span class="k-widget k-datepicker k-header" ng-class="{validationControl: !startDateValid}">

<span class="k-widget k-datepicker k-header" ng-class="{validationControl: !endDateValid}">
```

As you see I have removed the `style="border: solid"` because it overrides border style set in CSS.

That's it. Now we have a working example, we do not manipulate DOM, but only performing business logic.

Hope it helpled.

Answer (score 1):

ng-change requires ng-model

```
<input type="text" kendo-date-picker="" id="endDateTextbox-0" ng-change="addBorderToControl('endDateTextbox-0')" ng-model="model1">
```

and you need Jquery.

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/118/)**

**-------------------------------------------**

**Edit:**

```
<input type="text" kendo-date-picker="" id="endDateTextbox-1" ng-change="addBorderToControl('endDateTextbox-1')" ng-model="model2">
```

change `ng-change="addBorderToControl('endDateTextbox-0')`
to `ng-change="addBorderToControl('endDateTextbox-1')`

**-------------------------------------------**

**Edit 2:**

without Jquery:

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/138/)**

Comment: by any chance can we use angular instead of Jquery?